# Event for interface with timer method

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I am using MVVM pattern for Xamarin Forms but my questions about mostly about C#.

I would like to create a event handler to control a custom status with a timer method. That works but I am not sure below approach really is correct?

**My questions about;**

- If I don't use `InvokeCustomStatusEvent` in `MyPageViewModel` 
  `CustomStatusEvent` can't raise. Is that necessary?
- When I deattach `MyService.CustomStatusChanged -=

  MyService_CustomStatusChanged;` in `MyPageViewModel` `Device.StartTimer`
  loop continue to run. I am using `bool CustomStatusLoop` to stop that. Is that correct approach?

Thank you in advance.

**IMyService.cs**

```
namespace MyAppService.Services
{
    public interface IMyService
    {
        event EventHandler<CustomStatusEventArgs> CustomStatusChanged;
        void InvokeCustomStatusEvent(int seconds);
        bool CustomStatusLoop { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**MyService.cs**

```
namespace MyAppService.Services
{

  public class CustomStatusEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public bool IsCustomEnable;
        public CustomStatusEventArgs(bool isCustomEnable)
        {
            IsCustomEnable = isCustomEnable;
        }
    }

     public class MyService : IMyService
    {

        private IPageDialogService PageDialogService { get; }

        public bool CustomStatusLoop { get; set; }

        public MyService(IPageDialogService pageDialogService)
        {
            PageDialogService = pageDialogService;
        }

        #region //> Events

        event EventHandler<CustomStatusEventArgs> CustomStatusEvent;

        readonly object objectLock = new object();

        event EventHandler<CustomStatusEventArgs> IMyService.CustomStatusChanged
        {
            add
            {
                lock (objectLock)
                {
                    CustomStatusEvent += value;
                }
            }
            remove
            {
                lock (objectLock)
                {
                    CustomStatusEvent -= value;
                }
            }
        }


        public void InvokeCustomStatusEvent(int seconds)
        {
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds), () =>
            {
                CustomStatusEvent?.Invoke(this, new CustomStatusEventArgs(IsCustomEnable()));
                return CustomStatusLoop;

            });

        }

        #endregion

        public bool IsCustomEnable()
        {
            return Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<ICustomDependencyService>().IsCustomEnable();
        }

    }

}
```

**MyPageViewModel.cs**

```
namespace MyAppService.ViewModels
{
    public class MyPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region //> Services

        private IPageDialogService PageDialogService { get; }
        public IMyService MyService { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region //> Constructor

        public HomePageViewModel
        (
            IPageDialogService pageDialogService,
            IMyService MyService,
            INavigationService navigationService
        ) : base(navigationService)
        {
            PageDialogService = pageDialogService;
            MyService = MyService;
        }

        public override void Initialize(INavigationParameters parameters)
        {
            base.Initialize(parameters);
            MyService_CustomStatusChanged(this, new CustomStatusEventArgs(MyService.IsCustomEnable()));
        }

        public override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            MyService.CustomStatusChanged += MyService_CustomStatusChanged;
            MyService.InvokeCustomStatusEvent(5);
            MyService.CustomStatusLoop = true;
        }

        public override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
            MyService.CustomStatusChanged -= MyService_CustomStatusChanged;
            MyService.CustomStatusLoop = false;

        }
    }

    private async void MyService_CustomStatusChanged(object sender, CustomStatusEventArgs e)
        {
            IsCustomEnable = e.IsCustomEnable;
        }


      private bool _isCustomEnable;
        public bool IsCustomEnable
        {
            get => _isCustomEnable;
            set => SetProperty(ref _isCustomEnable, value);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> If I don't use InvokeCustomStatusEvent in MyPageViewModel CustomStatusEvent can't raise. Is that necessary?

Most of the time, events should come from the *inside* of a class, so there normally aren't any `RaiseMyEventForMe` methods. A notable exception is the `DelegateCommand`, but that one's there explicitly to *not* have a class for each command (that could then raise the event from inside).

> When I deattach MyService.CustomStatusChanged -= MyService_CustomStatusChanged; in MyPageViewModel Device.StartTimer loop continue to run. I am using bool CustomStatusLoop to stop that. Is that correct approach?

I'd rather use a `CancellationToken` to make clear what's happening, i.e. that you want to stop the timer when detaching the event.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I have wrote in here because my experience is not strong about similar approach. Can you explain to me in code, please?